# pySpark : add value to an empty array without 'null'

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, null

I'm building a repository to test a list of data and I intend to gather errors in a single column of array type. Therefore, I create the column first, then perform each test, and if one fails, I add an error message in the dedicated column.

My concern is when I add the first value: I still have a `null` value and I cannot manage to avoid this nor to remove it.

Here is some pieces of code I tried.
First version: the basic way I would expect:

```py
df = df.withColumn("errors", F.array(F.lit(None)))

df = df.withColumn(
    "errors",
    F.when(
        ((F.col("col1").isNull()) | ~(F.col("col1").rlike(r"\b[A-Z]{3,3}"))),
        F.array_union(F.col("errors"), F.array(F.lit("col1 is not valid"))),
    ),
)
```

The result when there is an error: `[null, col1 is not valid]`

I tried to check if there already are some values in the array:

```py
df = df.withColumn("errors", F.array(F.lit(None)))

df = df.withColumn(
    "errors",
    F.when(
        ((F.col("col1").isNull()) | ~(F.col("col1").rlike(r"\b[A-Z]{3,3}"))),
        F.when(
            F.size(F.col("errors")) == -1, F.array(F.lit("col1 is not valid"))
        ).otherwise(
            F.array_union(F.col("errors"), F.array(F.lit("col1 is not valid")))
        ),
    ),
)
```

but the result is exactly the same.

Any idea to manage this? Should I proceed a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this instead:

```
df = df.withColumn("errors", F.lit(None).cast("array<string>"))

df = df.withColumn(
    "errors",
    F.when(
        F.col('col1').isNull() | ~F.col('col1').rlike(r'\b[A-Z]{3,3}'),
        F.coalesce(
            F.concat(F.col("errors"), F.array(F.lit("col1 is not valid"))),
            F.array(F.lit("col1 is not valid"))
        )
    )
)
```

`errors` column is first created with null value, then use coalesce function

---

Or if you prefer, you can remove the `null` value from `errors` column at the end like this:

```
.withColumn(
    "errors",
    F.array_except("errors", F.array(F.lit(None)))
)

# or using filter
.withColumn(
    "errors",
    F.expr("filter(errors, x -> x is not null)")
)
```

Comment: Did you test my original code? I really would like to know, because your second part works fine for me, but not the first one. I don't understand why my code does not work, if your solution works for you, but not for me, might I have a bug on my platform?

Comment: @Christophe hum this is weird.. are you sure you changed the line where you first create the column `errors` as in my answer? `F.lit(None).cast("array<string>")`

Comment: actually, it looks like it's THE solution: with this `cast`, my own code works!

Comment: @Christophe no problem. Note however that there is no need to to use `F.size("errors") == -1` is this case. Simply check if `F.("errors").isNull()` of use `coalesce` function as shown above.

Comment: you're right, it's one of my numerous tries to find a solution, I didn't know this could come from the original initialization that I already used many times!